# Show that first order equation $|y'|+|y|=-1$ has no solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> Show that first order equation $$|y'|+|y|=-1$$ has no solution

**case 1** 
$y'>0$ and $y>0$, equation becomes
$y'=-(1+y) .$ Solution: $y=K_1e^{-x} -1$

**case 2** 
$y'>0$ and $y<0$, equation becomes
$y'=-(1-y) .$ Solution: $y=K_2e^{x} +1$

**case 3** 
$y'<0$ and $y>0$, equation becomes
$y'=(1+y) .$ Solution: $y=K_3e^{x} -1$

**case 4** 
$y'<0$ and $y<0$, equation becomes
$-y'=(-1+y) .$ Solution: $y=K_4e^{-x}+1$

Each case I got different solutions. How to prove that solution doesn't exist? Please help me.

Comment: The equation $|a|+|b|  +1 = 0$ has no solutions.

Comment: yes. @copper.hat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Note that we have
$$|x| \geq 0$$

What can you say about the sign on the left, what about the sign on the right?

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Why didn't I think!!!Why did I solve !!!:(